# How to track In-App Refund in ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have seen post related to the in-app purchases and and cannot find any solution for what I am looking for or may be cannot get the answers right.

The scene is that I have successfully implemented in-app and unlocked the purchased contents by setting a value to YES in NSUserDefaults.

Problem is this that if user gets a refund for the in-app the value remains YES in NSUserDefaults and he can still use the premium features.

I have read post about verifying the receipt with Apple servers and check for the cancellation date field but when I am getting the JSON response from the Apple server it contains no cancellation date field.

This is what I am recieving from Apple as JSON.

```
{
environment = Sandbox;
receipt =     {
    "adam_id" = 0;
    "app_item_id" = 0;
    "application_version" = 1;
    "bundle_id" = "com.company.bundleidentifier";
    "download_id" = 0;
    "in_app" =         (
                    {
            "is_trial_period" = false;
            "original_purchase_date" = "2015-11-24 15:15:01 Etc/GMT";
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1448378101000;
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2015-11-24 07:15:01 America/Los_Angeles";
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000181657877;
            "product_id" = myinappid;
            "purchase_date" = "2015-11-24 15:15:01 Etc/GMT";
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1448378101000;
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2015-11-24 07:15:01 America/Los_Angeles";
            quantity = 1;
            "transaction_id" = 1000000181657877;
        }
    );
    "original_application_version" = "1.0";
    "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";
    "receipt_creation_date" = "2015-11-26 06:38:22 Etc/GMT";
    "receipt_creation_date_ms" = 1448519902000;
    "receipt_creation_date_pst" = "2015-11-25 22:38:22 America/Los_Angeles";
    "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;
    "request_date" = "2015-11-26 06:52:30 Etc/GMT";
    "request_date_ms" = 1448520750619;
    "request_date_pst" = "2015-11-25 22:52:30 America/Los_Angeles";
    "version_external_identifier" = 0;
};
status = 0;
```

}

Can anyone tell me to solve the problem and suggest me some possible solution to lock the premium contents back if a user get refund.

Comment: If you aren't using a subscription in-app purchase then you get no notification of a refund.  The user just gets it for free and you lose out.

Comment: I am using a non-consumable in-app. So you mean I can't do anything to control this and I should stop digging.

Comment: That's about the size of it